# Is there any function I can use in python to achieve the Matlab function qtdecomp?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, scikit-image

I need to write code in python to achieve 

`S = qtdecomp(ampad, @(M) squeeze(sum(sum(M))) > thr );`

In which, ampad is a matrix and `thr` denotes the threshold value.
But I haven't found any toolbox in python that have a similar function. Is there anything I can use to achieve the goal quickly?

thx.

Comment: I haven't seen this before either. Can you post a link to a complete usage example? Where is this used? Perhaps we could add it to scikit-image.

Comment: ampad = zeros(dim,dim);
ampad(1:ydim,1:xdim) = am;
vrpad = false(dim,dim);
vrpad(1:ydim,1:xdim) = variables;
pmpad = false(dim,dim);
pmpad(1:ydim,1:xdim) = perim;
thr = settings.qt_sum;
ampad = ampad/max(ampad(vrpad));
ampad(pmpad) = thr;
S = qtdecomp(ampad, @(M) squeeze(sum(sum(M))) > thr );
fS = full(S);
fS = fS(1:ydim,1:xdim);
qtmask = fS > 0 & variables;

Comment: It's something like that in Matlab. What the qtdecomp function do is that it does a quad tree decomposition for an image and return a sparsity matrix representing the result of the decomposition. I really hope it can be implemented in scikit-image. It took a lot of efforts to implement it.

Comment: What I mean is, what do you do with the quad tree afterwards? Why is it useful?

Comment: I need to solve a function in which the matrix of the picture is very large, so I have to use a quad tree decomposition to compress the pic and get an approximate solution by solving the equation. The quad tree decomposition is used for sampling in my problem,